# How to stop heroku build in progress

Tags: node.js, heroku

I accidentally added `npm start` in the heroku post build process so now the build progress is stuck.

I did `git push heroku master` the build started normal and my server started as it should when running `npm start`, but because the `npm start` was in the post build it never finished. Because I'm on free account I only have one concurrent build process and because of the one stuck I can't build new version.

I already tried `heroku ps -a APP_NAME` and then `heroku ps:kill web.1` for the single process that was running, but it didn't help.

ty

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Struggling with the same thing now

Comment: I just waited it out. It takes aprox 3h to force quit. I also contacted the support and they said that they are working on stop feature

Comment: It did end up taking about the same amount of time for me - luckily it wasn't 24 hours. Thanks for the response.

Comment: There is a stop command available now. The syntax would be `heroku ps:stop $id -a $app`. You may find the `$id` from the command: `heroku ps -a $app`. Official documentation can be found [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase#canceling-a-release-command).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heroku has a [CLI Plugin](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-builds#cancel-build) with which you can manage your builds.

```
heroku builds -a example-app # take note of the build ID you'd want to display
heroku builds:cancel <id> -a example-app
```

In case anybody reading this might still need it!